# Regular dependence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have seen the definition of "regular dependence" in many books (usually old books), but I could not fully understand that definition, hope you can help me understand it.

The dependence of $X$ and $Y$ is called "regular" if the joint distribution is absolutely continuous with respect to the product distribution, i.e., $P_{XY}\ll P_XP_Y$.

I am wondering if we have any random variables which are not regularly dependent..

Any example in which $P_{XY}\ll P_XP_Y$ is violated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct statement is that $P_{(X,Y)}\ll P_X\otimes P_Y$.

For a counterexample, assume that $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$ and that $Y=X$, then $P_X\otimes P_Y$ is the uniform distribution on $(0,1)^2$  while $P_{(X,Y)}$ is the uniform distribution on the diagonal $D=\{(x,x)\mid x\in(0,1)\}$, hence $P_{(X,Y)}(D)=1$ and $(P_X\otimes P_Y)(D)=0$. This prevents the property that $P_{(X,Y)}\ll P_X\otimes P_Y$ to hold.

Comment: Thanks, so it is not true that whenever $X=Y$, then $P_{(X,Y)}\ll P_X\otimes P_{Y}$ does not hold. Right?

Comment: ?? It is true that if $X=Y$ almost surely then $P_{(X,Y)}\ll P_X\otimes P_Y$ cannot hold except if $X$ is almost surely constant.